# Gitlab set the merge request to use rebase instead of merge

Tags: git, gitlab

Gitlab does a merge operation every time it merges, which seems very annoying. And there is no rebase button option. How do I set it up?

Comment: this is not a duplicate, and the solution is suggesting a fast forward, not a rebase option, did I understand wrong?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. You can use quick action [`/rebase`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/git_rebase.html#rebase-from-the-gitlab-ui) in the merge-request comment to trigger a rebase. I haven't tested yet but plan to try it.

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at `Settings` -> `General` -> `Merge requests`. Here you can configure the merge options.
If you configure a fast-forward merge, no merge commit is created and you get the rebase option if a merge conflict exists.

[image]

Comment: this is not a proper answer, this is talking about fast forwardin, wich is an option when merging two branches, the proper answer today is: gitlab is not supporting a rebase button if you want to keep your branch visible after merge